# How do you call the effect of intense disgust when faced with (something)?

Tags: phobia

Phobia is defined ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobia), [DSM-5](https://dsm.psychiatryonline.org/)) as

> [the] persistent and excessive fear of an object or situation.

It seems that psychiatrists do not classify as phobia reactions of intense disgust or repulsion, without a fear component.

Such a reaction can be triggered by anything and many of these triggers do not inspire fear but rather the reactions I described above (source: reading several forums on phobias)

**My question**: how do you call the effect of intense, life-impacting disgust when faced with (something)?

*<sub>Note: this is a complete rewrite of a previous question, hopefully more aligned with the rules of the community</sub>*